# STS compiles .groovy as .java

Tags: eclipse, grails, groovy

I ran into a problem using Springsource Tool Suite when writing some groovy scripts to use with grails.

I really dont know what changed, but since starting STS today it tries to compile my. groovy files as .java. As you can imagine without any success.

I ran through all the settings of eclipse but didnt find any settings lloking wrong. Any ideas what could be the problem?

Comment: Does it list the project as a grails project? On of the builders is misconfigured.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I dont know what happend, but here's what solved the problem:

- delete .project and .classpath
- run grails integrate-with --eclipse

Answer (score 0):

Did you run an update lately?  The problem sounds like your groovy-JDT patch is no longer installed.  First, take a look at your error log.  You might see something like this in one of your entries:

> Error creating Groovy language support

If so, then you should update to the latest Groovy-Eclipse dev snapshot.  Use the following update site:

> http://dist.codehaus.org/groovy/distributions/greclipse/snapshot/e3.7/